# What's the most optimized algorithm (approach) for traversing a tree, ever?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, tree, tree-traversal

As it's stated in wikipedia there are multiple algorithms for traversing a tree data structure. But some of the algorithms are kind of combinations of the others, like Bidirectional search which is almost useful for other graphs rather than trees. But with a tree we almost have no idea of the end of the tree and we can only start from the root or from its children.

In this case we might be able to incorporate the multiprocessing or multithreading in search process. But I couldn't find any comprehensive approach that's described this.

Now my question is that basically what's the most optimized way of traversing a tree when we don't have access to the whole data structure (to be able to index them, etc. like a file directory)?

Comment: What is this actually for? If it’s a filesystem, for example, there are usually faster ways to get a list of every file than the straightforward ones (because you *can* actually “have access to the whole data structure”). You’re not going to do better than linear time, though.

Answer (score 6):

The most optimized algorithm is usually the one optimized for specific usecase and platform.

It does not matter whether you do inorder, preorder or postorder. Or whether you do DFS or BFS.
What matters is:

- How big is the tree? Does it fit into memory?
- How deep is the tree? Can you use recursion, or do you have to use explicit separate stack?
- How do you find children of the node. Do you have to access harddrive/network?
- What do you want to do with the node after you find in traversal. If this operation is long enough, optimizing traversal is not worth it.
- How do you share data between threads?
- How are the nodes in the tree distributed? Does it resemble even distribution, or are there some very long and some very short branches?
- How big are the node keys (this influences data locality and how much data you can fit into one L1/L2 cache line)?

Answer (score -2):

Try in order traversing of Binary Search tree. The complexity of search is nlogn and traverse is n, which is considered to be the best.

Ex: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/

Comment: In-order binary tree traversal is ϴ(n), not ϴ(n log n), time.

Comment: Search is O(nlogn), where as traversal is O(n) as you said. Not sure if there exists an algorithm to traverse all elements less than O(n). So harsh on downgrade my answer which affected my reputations.

Comment: I believe he is looking for a multithreaded/distributed search

Comment: Search is O(log n) on a balanced BST – saying it’s O(n log n) is misleading – but it doesn’t matter because the question asked for a traversal, and there are lots of linear-time traversals that don’t require BSTs or balance.